# missing \begin{document}, undefined environment \cvcolumns and control sequence \cvcolumn

Tags: moderncv

My tex installation is from the ubuntu PPA. I am trying to compile a moderncv class type file with it. The MWE has been given below. For some reason the compilation returns errors:

1. missing `\begin{document}`
2. undefined environment `\cvcolumns`
3. undefined control sequence `\cvcolumn`

The same is compiling successfully in another system with some other version.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv} % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\moderncvstyle{casual} % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\nopagenumbers{} % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% personal data
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{Sushanta}%<first name%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\familyname{Sahu}%<family name%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\title{}%<Resumé title%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\address{D-106, SSB Hall}{National Institute of Technology, Rourkela}{769008}%<street and number%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<postcode city%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<country%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted; the "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\mobile{9937488818}%<mobile number%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
%\phone{}%<phone number%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
%\fax{}%<fax number%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\email{sushanta.sahu@outlook.com}%<email%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{http://sengerandu.wordpress.com}%<home page%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{}%<additional information%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\photo[100pt][0.4pt]{sushanta.jpg}%<picture%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, uncomment the line if wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{}%<some quote%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
%
\begin{document}
%----- resume ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{2011-Present}{Ph.D}{National Institute of Technology}{Rourkela}{}{Mechanical Engineering(Production)}%<year%:columnShift:-13,persistent%>%<year%:columnShift:-11,persistent%>%<Degree%:columnShift:-9,persistent%>%<Institution%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<City%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Grade%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Description%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{2007-2009}{M.Tech}{National Institute of Technology}{Rourkela}{}{Metallurgical and Materials Engineering(Composites)}%<year%:columnShift:-13,persistent%>%<year%:columnShift:-11,persistent%>%<Degree%:columnShift:-9,persistent%>%<Institution%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<City%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Grade%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Description%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cventry{2002-2006}{B.E}{Padmashree Krutartha Acharya College of Engineering}{Bargarh}{}{Mechanical Engg}%<year%:columnShift:-13,persistent%>%<year%:columnShift:-11,persistent%>%<Degree%:columnShift:-9,persistent%>%<Institution%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<City%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Grade%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Description%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\section{Theses}
\cvitem{Ph.D}{Investigation on Laser Welding of Dissimilar Metal Tubes} %<title%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Title%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitem{Supervisor}{Prof. S K Sahoo}%<supervisors%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Supervisors%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitem{Abstract}{}
%\section{Theses}
\cvitem{M.Tech}{An appraisal of Characteristic Mechanical Properties of Aluminium 6061 alloy – Silicon Carbide (SiC$_\text{P}$) Metal Matrix Composite (MMC) exposed to different thermal conditions. }%<title%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Title%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitem{Supervisor}{Prof. U K Mohanty}%<supervisors%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Supervisors%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitem{Abstract}{Coated ceramic particle reinforced metal matrix composite had been prepared through the solid state sintering route. The effects of sintering temperature, holding time and various thermal shock on the mechanical properties had been investigated in this work. The fracture behavior of the composite had been investigated vis-a-vis duration of predicted service life.}%<description%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Short thesis abstract%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\section{Experience}
\cventry{2011-2014}{SRF}{SRICCE, NIT}{Rourkela}{Worked under a project for BRNS, DAE}{SRF}
%\cventry{--}{}{}{}{}{}%<year%:columnShift:-13,persistent%>%<year%:columnShift:-11,persistent%>%<Job title%:columnShift:-9,persistent%>%<Employer%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<City%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<General description no longer than 1--2 lines%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cventry{2010-2011}{Asst-Professor}{TITE, Knowledge Trust}{Khurda}{}
{Managed the Department as the HOD; Managed the Examination section as VP-Exam Committee; Successfully revived the pedagogy in the Institute being a core member of the task-force, resulting in reduction in backlog of the students.}
\cventry{2009-2010}{Lecturer}{Padmashree Krutartha Acharya College of Engineering}{Bargarh}{}{Supervised 14 student projects of various disciplines, that had potential for conversion to CSR projects. Managed the Sports and Cultural events of the institute in the capacity of VP. Supervised the organization of the annual technical festival \emph{Sizzling-10} with a budget of 3.5 Lacs and external guest size of 120. }
\cventry{2006-2007}{Lecturer}{Padmashree Krutartha Acharya College of Engineering}{Bargarh}{}{}
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Hindi}{Proficient}{Can compose literary items}%<Language 1%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Skill level%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Proficient}{}%<Language 2%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Skill level%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitemwithcomment{}{}{}%<Language 3%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Skill level%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{Softwares}{ANSYS, OpenFOAM, Elmer, Code-ASTER, Salome, MATLAB}{}{}%<Category 1%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Category 4%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvdoubleitem{Languages}{C/C++, Python}{}{}%<Category 2%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Category 5%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvdoubleitem{}{}{}{}%<Category 3%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Category 6%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\section{Interests}
\cvitem{}{}%<Hobby 1%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Description%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitem{}{}%<Hobby 2%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Description%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvitem{}{}%<Hobby 3%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Description%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\section{Publications}
\cvlistitem{Moharana B R, Sahoo S K and \textbf{Sahu S K}, Optimization of processing parameters in welding of two dissimilar metal by pulsed Nd:YAG laser, 1$^\text{st}$ Proceedings of the International Conference on Material Science, Tripura, India(2013)}%<Item 1%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvlistitem{Moharana B R, Sahoo S K and \textbf{Sahu S K}, Fuzzy rule based prediction of Tensile strength for dissimilar metal joints, Proceedings of 3$^\text{rd}$ International Conference on Production and Industrial Engineering, Jalandhar (2013)}%<Item 2%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
%\cvlistitem{}%<Item 3%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
%\section{Extra 2}
%\cvlistdoubleitem{}{}%<Item 1%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Item 4%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
%\cvlistdoubleitem{}{}%<Item 2%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Item 5%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
%\cvlistdoubleitem{}{}%<Item 3%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Item 6%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
\cvcolumn{Prof. S K Sahoo}{Professor\\Dept. of ME, NITR}%<Category 1%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvcolumn{Dr. Piyu Tripathy}{Director\\ TITE, Khurda}%<Category 2%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\cvcolumn{Prof. D R K Parhi}{Professor\\ Dept. of ME, NITR}%<Category 3%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Comment%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\end{cvcolumns}
\clearpage
%----- letter ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{OPJIT\\Raigarh}{Chattisgarh\\ India\\}%<Company Recruitment team%:columnShift:-7,persistent%>%<Company's name%:columnShift:-5,persistent%>%<Street address%:columnShift:-3,persistent%>%<Zip Code City%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\date{\today}%<Date%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\opening{Dear Sir/Madam,}%<Dear Sir or Madam,%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\closing{Yours faithfully,}%<Yours faithfully,%:columnShift:-1,persistent%>
\enclosure{\begin{itemize}
\item curriculum vitae
\item supporting documents
\item Certificates
\end{itemize}}
%<enclosures%:columnShift:-1,persistent%> % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle
%body %< Matter of the letter should be written here %>
I am writing to you apropos your advertisement on your website regarding a faculty position in the Department of Mechanical Engineering at your Institute.

I was fortunate enough to have started my teaching career at my Alma Mater right after my graduation. Thereafter I went for higher studies and came back for another stint. Hoping for better, I moved to Knowledge Trust at Khurda where the Departmental Head went for his higher studies. And I was entrusted with managing the affairs of the department. Being a newly established Institute (a sister concern of the famed KIIT group), it offered good learning in terms of laboratory setup, documentation, recruitment, automation. I was entrusted with additional duties of managing examinations. I was also absorbed into the core-team of an institutional task-force created for reforming the pedagogical approach to clear up backlog of the students. Both the experiences were satisfying and culminated with appreciable results.

Having got a chance to work in a DAE funded project, I joined as a SRF at NIT Rourkela and simultaneously enrolled for PhD. During the course of the project I gained knowledge about project management life cycle, handled various equipments, developed various equipments and attachments, got to visit many premier R\&D institutions and plants. The course works offered in during PhD also unraveled many new avenues for study.

Given that your Institute is closely related with industry and is in close vicinity of it, there would be immense scope for industrial research if the Institute favors such activities. Along with regular teaching, effort can be directed at research work too. Your Institute being a promoter of quality education and an aspirant of reaching new heights in the Country, it would be a pleasure and privilege to be a part of it and contribute in this regard.

I look forward for being considered a potent candidate and eagerly wait a few words from your end for a meeting.

%\vspace*{10mm}
\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Try adding `\listfiles` to the beginning of the document.  It will then print in the `.log` file version numbers for the files used.  My guess is that these are different on your two systems.  Your posted code compiles (essentially) fine for me

Comment: FYI, your code works fine with my latex distribution under linux.

Comment: The most likely cause for the `\cvcolumns` and `\cvcolumn` commands not being defined, is that the system you are compiling on relies on an old version of `moderncv`. Check the version being used in the `.log`.

Comment: Thank you @Xavier. Your apprehensions were correct. Bu following the steps I found that the version was in deed old. The problem was solved by installing the entire texlive chain from latest DVD source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by updating the TeX distribution (and `moderncv`).